Show that $f(b) - f(a) \geq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(f(b_n)-f(a_n))$
Let $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be an increasing function and suppose that:

$A = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty(a_n,b_n]\ \ (\text{ disjoint union }) \ \ (a_n \leq b_n; ,a_n ,b_n \in [-\infty, \infty])$;

$A\subseteq [a,b] \ \ (a<b; a,b \in [-\infty,\infty])$


Denote $f(\infty) = \sup f, f(-\infty) = \inf f$
I need to show that $f(b) - f(a) \geq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(f(b_n)-f(a_n))$ for my homework. My idea was to show that $f(b) - f(a) \geq \sum_{n= 1}^m(f(b_n)-f(a_n)),\  \forall m \geq 1$. But I still don't know how to proceed. Could anyone help me?

$A$ is irrelevant. Simply assume $-\infty\le a\le a_n\le b_n\le b\le\infty$ and the intervals $(a_n,b_n]$ are disjoint. And once you reduced the problem to the case of $m$ intervals, you may assume $b_k\le a_{k+1}$ $(\forall k=1,\dots,m-1)$.
